# Join tables and Concatenate Multiple Rows Within Single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Join multiple table and concatenate multiple rows into one for distinct department names.

I was able to do it on table EmpDepartment but I need to join all table.
Expected output like this.

Need Query

| EmpID | EmpName | DepartmentName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | q,w,e |
| 2 | B | Null |

[image: ER DIAGRAM]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  p.EmpID,
  EmpName,
  STRING_AGG(DepartmentName,',') as DepartmentName
FROM
  EmpPayroll p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  EmpDepartment e on e.EmpID=p.EmpID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  Department d on d.deptID=e.deptID
GROUP BY
  p.EmpID,
  EmpName
```

if you're on SQL Server 2017 or later.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: getting this error 
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 9
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
i am using MSSMS 18

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18369.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.46041.41
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19342.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.19042

Comment: @user8886083 we don't care about your SSMS version, run `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 6.3 <X64> (Build 19042: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

I updated as per your request.

If you are using SQL Server 2017 and above Versions

```
SELECT ED.EmpId
      ,EP.EmpName
      ,STRING_AGG(D.DepartmentName,',') AS DepartmentName
FROM EmpPayroll EP 
  LEFT JOIN EmpDepartment ED
         ON EP.EmpId = ED.EmpId
  LEFT JOIN Department D 
         ON D.DeptId = ED.DeptId
Group By ED.EmpId, EP.EmpName
```

and for SQL Server 2016 and Below Versions

```
;WITH Partitioned AS
(
    
    SELECT EP.EmpId, EP.EmpName,D.DepartmentName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ED.EmpId ORDER BY D.DepartmentName) AS NameNumber,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ED.EmpId) AS NameCount  
    FROM EmpPayroll EP
    LEFT JOIN EmpDepartment  ED 
           ON EP.EmpId = ED.EmpId
    LEFT JOIN Department D 
           ON D.DeptId = ED.DeptId

),
Concatenated AS
(
    SELECT 
        EmpId, 
        CAST(DepartmentName AS nvarchar) AS DepartmentName, 
        EmpName, 
        NameNumber, 
        NameCount 
    FROM Partitioned 
    WHERE NameNumber = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        P.EmpId, 
        CAST(P.DepartmentName + ', ' + C.DepartmentName AS nvarchar), 
        P.EmpName, 
        P.NameNumber, 
        P.NameCount
    FROM Partitioned AS P
        INNER JOIN Concatenated AS C 
                ON P.EmpId = C.EmpId 
                AND P.NameNumber = C.NameNumber + 1
)
SELECT 
    EmpId,
    EmpName,
    DepartmentName
FROM Concatenated
WHERE NameNumber = NameCount
```

Comment: thank you very much this works,
i also want to add employee in table even if deparment is null

Comment: Hey, Is the above solution works for you? if so, please mark this as answer and upvote